# Compactness of the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness, stereographic-projections

Let us consider the plane $P = \{(x, y, -1) \in \mathbb{R}^3\}$ in three dimensional space. It is a closed set, but because it isn't bounded, it isn't compact. Now take the sphere without a pole: 
$$S^2_* = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3\mid x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1\} - \{(0,0,1)\}$$
It is bounded by the sphere itself, and it's also a closed set. Thus, it is a compact set. Then comes stereographic projection, giving a continuous bijection between $P$ and $S^2_*$ - but $S^2_*$ is compact and continuous functions take compact sets to compact sets! Clearly, $P$ is not compact, so something fishy is going on here.

My guess is that stereographic projection continuity is the problem - maybe I'm considering the wrong topologies on those sets. But ain't the subspace topology on $P$ the same as the metric topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$? I see open disks corresponding to the intersection of open balls with the plane. Or is the problem in the closeness of $S^2_*$? I guess the pole missing ain't an interior point of the complement..

Comment: When you remove the pole from the sphere, it's no longer closed.

Comment: $S^2_*$ is not closed.

Comment: Every open neighborhood of $(0,0,1)$ intersects $S_*^2;$ therefore $(0,0,1)$ is a limit point of $S_*^2.$ Since it's a limit point of $S_*^2$ but not a member of $S_*^2,$ it follows that $S_*^2$ is not closed. Also, $(0,0,1)$ cannot be an interior point of the complement of $S_*^2$ since every open neighborhood of $(0,0,1)$ intersects $S_*^2.$ Hence the complement of $S_*^2$ is not open. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sphere without a pole $S^{2}_*$ is not a closed set because its complement is not open.

The complement is not open because it includes the sphere's pole, which violates the [neighborhood condition for open sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_set#Euclidean_space).